# Blackberry - using EventInjector to ignore incoming call

Tags: events, blackberry, call, listener

Hello everyone' I'm trying to use an EventInjector in my app to automatically dismiss all incoming calls. My MainScreen implements PhoneListener. Below is my code

```
public void callIncoming(int callId) {
            requestForeground();
            final PhoneCall call = Phone.getCall(callId);  
            final String number = call.getDisplayPhoneNumber();  
            System.out.println(number);  
            EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent pressEndKey = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(  
                    KeyCodeEvent.KEY_DOWN, (char) Keypad.KEY_END, 0, 100);  
            EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent releaseEndKey = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(  
                    KeyCodeEvent.KEY_UP, (char) Keypad.KEY_END, 0, 100);

            EventInjector.invokeEvent(pressEndKey);  
            EventInjector.invokeEvent(releaseEndKey);   
        }
```

This code isn't working, in otherwords in has no effect. The incoming call screen continues to popup and won't go away until an action is taken.

Comment: I don't know if this will impact it, but does your app have the "Input Simulation" permission turned to Allow?

Comment: Yes it is, enabled EventInjection in the IT policy of the sim too

Comment: Have you debugged it to make sure it's hitting this block of code?

Comment: Silly me. I had to add Phone.addPhoneListener(this); to the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this link, it works!

http://www.codinguru.com/2011/08/block-incoming-call-in-blackberry.html

```
public void callIncoming(int callId) {
        final PhoneCall call = Phone.getCall(callId);  
        final String number = call.getDisplayPhoneNumber();  
        System.out.println(number);  

        EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent pressEndKey = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent( KeyCodeEvent.KEY_DOWN, (char) Keypad.KEY_END, 0, 100);  
        EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent releaseEndKey = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent( KeyCodeEvent.KEY_UP, (char) Keypad.KEY_END, 0, 100);  

        try {  
            Thread.sleep(1000);  
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        EventInjector.invokeEvent(pressEndKey);  
        EventInjector.invokeEvent(releaseEndKey);  
    }
```

Comment: The link is to a private blog.